# Sequential almost sure continuity implies almost sure continuity

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(B_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a real stochastic process. $\forall\omega\in\Omega$, let $f_\omega(t) = B_t(\omega)$.

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $(B_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is almost surely continuous at $x$ iff $f_\omega$ is continuous at $x$ for almost all $\forall\omega\in\Omega$.

Define sequential almost sure continuity at $x$ this way: $\forall (x_n)_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$, such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, it's almost sure that $B_{x_n} \rightarrow B_x$.

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, is it true that sequential almost sure continuity at $x$ implies almost sure continuity at $x$?

If not, then also assume that, $(B_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is almost surely continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$. That is, $f_\omega$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\}$ for almost all $\forall\omega\in\Omega$. Would that be enough to show almost sure continuity at $x$?

Comment: They are not equivalent. Consider the standard Brownian motion on $[0,1]$, and modify it to be equal to zero on the random countable set $\{U_n:n \in \Bbb N\}$, where $U_n$ are iid uniform on $[0,1]$. Then that process will be sequentially continuous according to your definition (indeed, it suffices to take monotone $x_n\to x$, in which case convergence follows from the martingale or reverse martingale convergence theorem). However, it won't be continuous at any point since the random set $\{U_n\}$ is a.s. dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Even with the stronger assumption, it is not true without additional conditions on your stochastic process. For instance it is enough if $B_t$ is a martingale (because then the convergence theorem tells you that $B_{x-1/n} \to B_x$ a.s, then you can just use the continuity condition). Also, Maud is great and you've made me want to indulge my mlpfim addiction (damn you).